# Cordova gallery not showing with cordova-plugin-image-picker

Tags: cordova, image-gallery, imagepicker

I have build an app using Cordova and vanilla JS and have been using cordova-plugin-image-picker to include images from the gallery.

I've been using it fine for several weeks, but yesterday it stopped working.
I now get the cancel and OK buttons at the top of the page, but can see no images in the gallery.

I'm pretty sure that the code is ok as I hadn't changed it and it works ok iOS (and I have rolled back to previous versions).

As a test I tried to create a new app that only contains a button that opens the gallery (to check that no other code or plugins in my app was interfering) but I got the same thing.

This is the code I'm using to open the gallery:

```
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }, {
        maximumImagesCount: 10,
        width: 800
    }
);
```

I've tried several devices and even compiled on a separate PC to eliminate problems with Android Studio.

Any ideas of anything I could try?

If I had hair, I would be pulling it out by now.
Everything was working until I packaged it up for deployment and that seemed to be the thing that has broken it.

All ideas will be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: i am also facing the same issue is there any fix available?

Comment: @AmbalMani, I gave up in the end. I went back to cordova.plugin.camera which works better except that i am not able to select multiple images at once.

Answer (score 0):

Check app permissions by going under settings on your device. If the device does not have permission to view the files, then nothing will show up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but it wasnt this. All permissions were set as they needed to be.